# How to change value of dictionary into 'set inside of list'

Tags: python, set

I have this kind of dictionary in Python:

```
{a: {1, 2, 3}, b: {3, 4, 5}, c: {5, 6, 7}}
```

I want to transform the values into set inside of list.

Expected value:

```
{a: [{1, 2, 3}], b: [{3, 4, 5}], c: {5, 6, 7}]}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why do you want to do that?

Comment: Wait am I dumb or is this not a dictionary ```{5, 6, 7}```

Comment: I think it's a set when used like that @Buddy

Comment: assuming you have `original = {'a': {1, 2, 3}, 'b': {3, 4, 5}, 'c': {5, 6, 7}}`, you may try `answer = {k: [v] for k, v in original.items()}`.

Comment: @VedankPande o right my bad

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
dict1= {"a": {1, 2, 3}, "b": {3, 4, 5}, "c": {5, 6, 7}}


new_dict = {key:[sub_set] for key,sub_set in dict1.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

output:

```
{'a': [{1, 2, 3}], 'b': [{3, 4, 5}], 'c': [{5, 6, 7}]}
```

Although, do you mind explaining why you want it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this seems like a pretty simple answer to your question.

```
dict1= {'a': {1, 2, 3}, 'b': {3, 4, 5}, 'c': {5, 6, 7}}
for x in dict1:dict1[x] = [dict1[x]]
print(dict1)
```

But like many other people here, I can't help by wonder. Why would you want this?

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Python and currently working on optimization case. I don't really know but it seems that the library works if i change the dict into the set inside of list

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values into sets in lists using the following way.

```
d = {'a': {1, 2, 3}, 'b': {3, 4, 5}, 'c': {5, 6, 7}}
for x in d.keys():
    d[x] = [d[x]]

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': [{1, 2, 3}], 'b': [{3, 4, 5}], 'c': [{5, 6, 7}]}
```